# Choosing projection for buffering polygons

Tags: coordinate-system, buffer

I'm working with an application that needs to manages (lat lon) polygons all over the globe. For some reasons i need sometimes to do some operations like buffering, for more convenience, I would like to use meters.

To give more details to my problem, I have a polygon, I need to make a grid that contains this polygon and I need for every mesh of the grid to overlap on the 4 others mesh around it.

The witdh and height of the grid are in meters and the overlaping too.

I already did all that work but I used EPSG:3857 projection. Now I would like to be more precise and adapt the projection first.

Is there a particular projection that could fit to my problem or I have to adapt it depending on the position of my input polygon on the globe?

Comment: It depends on what you neet the grid for. If it is just some arbitrary cooridnate values and if you are fine with the heavy distortions that come with Mercator projections, EPSG:3857 is fine. If you want real world measurements, you must use different CRS. For worldwide datasets, I would use the local UTM zones.

Comment: I will try this way, thank you.

Comment: I think this : https://spatialthoughts.com/2019/04/05/geodesic-buffers-in-qgis/ is the answer

Comment: The ST_Buffer with the geography data type https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html in PostGIS  tries to do automatically what is required for a reasonable result. "For geography this is a thin wrapper around the geometry implementation.

It determines a planar spatial reference system that best fits the bounding box of the geography object (trying UTM, Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area (LAEA) North/South pole, and finally Mercator ). The buffer is computed in the planar space, and then transformed back to WGS84." I would try that.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36528805/439194 for one possible solution

Comment: https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.estimate_utm_crs.html